# Avoid opening another windows when file is opening

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem. I would like to implement macro which will go to error-handler when user does not have access to file, but err.description does not help because when I want to open appropriate file, window where I have to insert login and password, and here is idea, when this unexpected window is displayed macro should go to error-handler but I do not how to implement it, below code will display mentioned window.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error GoTo AccessProblem
Workbooks.Open filename=:"link to file"
'here login window is displayed
AccessProblem:
MsgBox err.Description
'If InStr(err.Description, "access") <> 0 Then
'    Range(somerange).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
'End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error GoTo AccessProblem
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open filename=:"link to file", password ="Not your password"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'here login window is displayed
AccessProblem:
MsgBox err.Description
'If InStr(err.Description, "access") <> 0 Then
'    Range(somerange).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
'End If
```

This is what you need to do. Disable alerts at the stage where you try and open - so it doesn't bombard you with errors, then put in a gobbledigook password so it won't open. This will trigger the error handler.

Comment: but I am sure that the file exists, I would like have possibility to check if file is opened immediately without any other windows

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - but you could have a look at the workbook open command in the thisworkbook object possibly - if you want to trigger something once it has been opened.

Comment: if the file is not opened because of access warning window in which i have to insert login and password , i want macro to skip this file

Comment: Do you mean to say that the file is password protected? And you want to only continue if the password is correctly input?

Comment: if password is needed i want to go to error-handler

Comment: I've edited the response so this should now work for you.